# Avoid duplicates in nested loop python

Tags: python, arrays

So i have nested loops and array 
`[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`:

```
for x in string_list:
        for y in string_list:
            print(x,y)
```

provides me the output

```
[0, 1] [0, 1]
[0, 1] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But i have a lot of duplicates pairs and i did:

```
for x in range(0, len(string_list)):
      for y in range(x+1, len(string_list)): 
          print(x,y, string_list)
```

but it's working only for 2 digit pairs.
So what i want is:

```
[0, 1] [0, 1]
[0, 1] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
[0, 1] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
**[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1]** // avoid to output that pair cause we had that one 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1]
**[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]** // avoid to output that pair cause we had that one 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

does it possible to do without using itertools ?
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `itertools`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for k, x in enumerate(string_list):
    for y in string_list[k:]:
        print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
for x, y in it.combinations(string_list, 2):
    # process x, y
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use `itertools`.

Comment: @DanielWalker That's not a legitimate argument. The standard library exists to be used. And it can be used with minimal effort, the functionality is just one import away.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWalker. Learned something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously using `itertools.combinations` is ideal, but since you said you don't want to use `itertools`, you could use a set comprehension to build the set of unique combinations (you have to convert the lists to tuples to make them hashable), then convert them back to lists as needed:

```
[list(list(t) for t in f) for f in {
    frozenset((tuple(x), tuple(y))) for y in string_list for x in string_list
}]
```

Comment: This gives the exact same output as OP his output.

Comment: needed an extra layer of settification in there, fixed.  :D

Comment: I might need a frozen set of ice cubes for the headache I now have. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can put a `continue` statement in the inner loop to skip duplicates:

```
 for x in string_list:
     for y in string_list:
         if x == y:
             continue
         print(x,y)
```

Comment: yes, but it will remove only:  [0, 1] [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], correct ? not what i want